# If the 'Accessibility Identifier' is intended for UI Automation tests, why is it included in localizable resources?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, accessibility, ui-automation

It appears that the `Accessibility Identifier` property has been added to allow UI automation tests to have a more stable ID. It's recommended to be used instead of the `Accessibility Label` as the label is used by Screen Readers and VoiceOver.

This makes sense, however:

1. Why is the `Accessibility Identifier` included as a translatable
   string resource when using the **Export for localization** feature in
   Xcode? This makes multi-language testing more difficult because it encourages a different ID in each language.
2. Why is the `Accessibility Identifier` associated with Accessibility at
   all? Why not call it UI Automation ID? Does the `Accessibility Identifier` actually get presented to screen readers, VoiceOver, other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After filing a bug with Apple, I got this response:

> This is definitely a bug we will fix, and you are correct that it isn’t presented to VoiceOver, or other screen readers

**Update:** Confirmed fixed in Xcode 8 GM